# Replacing all subsequences in a list

Tags: pattern-matching

How do I replace all occurrences of -1,1 with 0,1 in a list

example:

```
list = {-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1}
```

desired output:

```
{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1}
```

I tried the following:

```
list/.{x___, -1, 1, y___} -> {x, 0, 1, y}
```

However, this only matches the first instance of the pattern. A working solution I found is this:

```
list//.{x___, -1, 1, y___} -> {x, 0, 1, y}
```

This scales atrociously though.

Comment: `SequenceReplace[list, {-1, 1} -> Sequence[0, 1]]`?

Comment: My version does not seem to support SequenceReplace

Comment: @MarcoB I am sorry for that, I saw your comment after I posted with a very similar answer.

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner I see. Could you add which version you are using to your question?

Comment: @Titus Not a problem! Actually, thank you for turning my comment into a proper answer :-)

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner I am confused why the accepted answer uses the function that your version, which you do not list, does not support? Can you please clarify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
bill = {-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1};
Flatten[SequenceReplace[bill, {-1, 1} :> {0, 1}]]
```

> {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1}

I also include the output without `Flatten`, it might be of interest as to how it works. The documentation can be found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html)

> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, 1, 1, -1, -1, {0, 1}}

**EDIT:** Courtesy of `@MarcoB` and `@Bob Hanlon`:

```
 SequenceReplace[bill, {-1, 1} :> Sequence[0, 1]]
```

Comment: Also `SequenceReplace[bill, {-1, 1} :> Sequence[0, 1]]`

Comment: what's the reason for  `RuleDelayed`  and not `Rule`? there is no need to evaluate `Sequence` each time it is replaced, am i wrong?

Comment: I posted a solution that is faster with a shorter `Trace` and does not use `SequenceReplace` (which is the obvious choice if it is applicable).

Comment: In version 12.1, `SequenceReplace[bill, {-1, 1} :> Splice[{0, 1}]]`

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution I came up with. It should work with 10.1+

```
ReplacePart[list, 
 Rule[#, 0] & /@ First /@ SequencePosition[list, {-1, 1}]]

(* {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1} *)
```

The length of the `Trace` is 4. Oddly, considering its messy implementation, this is shorter than the length of the `Trace` for the solution in Titus's answer, which is 5.

```
Length@Trace@
  ReplacePart[list, 
   Rule[#, 0] & /@ First /@ SequencePosition[list, {-1, 1}]]
Length@Trace@SequenceReplace[list, {-1, 1} :> Sequence[0, 1]]

(* 4 *)
(* 5 *)
```

The solution is also somehow faster, this might be given due to the shorter length of the `Trace`. That would mean that it scales better than that of Titus's solution.

```
ReplacePart[list, 
   Rule[#, 0] & /@ First /@ SequencePosition[list, {-1, 1}]] // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
SequenceReplace[list, {-1, 1} :> Sequence[0, 1]] // 
  RepeatedTiming // First


(* 0.000034 *)
(* 0.000078 *)
```

Hope you find that this helps for the version that you are on.

Answer (score 3):

```
Join[  #[[;; -2, 1]], # [[-1]] ] &@ (Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, 2}] /. {-1, 1} -> {0, 1})
```

Comment: @SubaThomas no it fails at the last element